# Differentiate: $f(\theta) = \frac{\sec \theta} {3 + \sec \theta}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I got $$\frac{(3+\sec \theta) (\cos\theta) - (\sec \theta) (3+\cos \theta)} { (3+\sec\theta)^2}$$

However the program that I am using says my answer is wrong. [image]

Comment: You seem to recognize that you should use the quotient rule which states $(\frac{f}{g})' = \frac{f'g-fg'}{g^2}$.  However, check what the derivative of $sec(\theta)$ is.  The derivative of sine is cosine, suggesting that the derivative of secant should be different.

Answer (score 1):

it may simplify to multiply numerator and denominator by $\cos \theta$ to obtain
$$
f(\theta) = \frac1{3\cos \theta + 1}
$$
so
$$
f'(\theta) = -\frac{-3\sin \theta}{(3 \cos \theta + 1)^2}=\frac{3\sec \theta \tan \theta}{(3+\sec \theta)^2}
$$

Answer (score 1):

The derivative of $\sec \theta$ is $\sec \theta \cdot \tan \theta$.

I would actually multiply the numerator and denominator by $\cos \theta$ first to get
$$f(\theta) = \frac{\sec \theta}{3 + \sec \theta} \cdot \frac{\cos \theta}{\cos \theta} = \frac{1}{3 \cos \theta + 1},$$
and then you can use the quotient rule or the chain rule to get that
$$f'(\theta) = \frac{3\sin \theta}{(3\cos \theta+1)^2}.$$